# Regex: Skip/Ignore pattern

Tags: regex

Given that the following string is embedded in text, how can I extract the whole line but not matching on the inner "<" and ">"?

```
<test type="yippie<innertext>" />
```

**EDIT**:
Being more specific, we need to handle both use cases below where "type" has or does not have "<" and ">" chars.

```
<h:test type="yippie<innertext>" />
<h:test type="yippie">

Group 1: 'h:test'
Group 2: ' type="yippie<innertext>" '  -or-  ' type="yippie"'   (ie, remaining content before ">" or "/>")
```

So far, I have something like this, but it's a little off how it Group 2 stops at the first ">".  Tweaking first part of Group 2's condition.

```
(<([a-zA-Z0-9_:-]+)([^>"]*|[^>]*?)\s*(/)?>)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<([:\w]+)(\s(?:"[^"]*"|[^/>"])+)/?>
```

Example usage (Python):

```
>>> x = '<h:test type="yippie<innertext>" />'
>>> re.search('<([:\w]+)(\s(?:"[^"]*"|[^/>"])+)/?>', x).groups()
('h:test', ' type="yippie<innertext>" ')
```

Also note that if your document is HTML or XML then you should use an HTML or XML parser instead of trying to do this with regular expressions.

Comment: Yep, you're on it.  I should have been more clear and complete.  I need to group the matching splitting the tag name and the remaining lot.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to parse XML/HTML with a regex. I would say that your approach is fundamentally wrong. A sufficiently advanced regex is not indistinguishable from an XML parser. After all, what if you needed to parse:

```
<test type="yippie<inner\"text\"_with_quotes,_literal_slash_and_quote\\\">" />
```

Furthermore, you probably need to escape the inner `<` and `>` as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

For further reasons why you should not parse XML with a regex, I can only yield to this superior answer:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I wish I could.  Existing implementation forces my hand.